# Is there an algorithm that provides the highest possible "sum of satisfaction" for a priority based distribution problem?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

Let's say we have n (e.g. 6) children and a box of candy. The box has k (e.g. 8) different flavours, and m (e.g. 4) piece of candy in each flavour. This question is specifically about the cases where k > n and n > m.

We can assume a maximum of a 1 piece of a flavour per person.

We ask them to make a list of the flavours from most liked to least liked, so we know the preferences of each child.

We of course want the "sum of satisfaction" to be the highest possible.

Is there an algorithm that is able to give the perfect distribution, or one that's quite close?

Comment: You can formulate this as an integer programming problem and solve it exactly using an off-the-shelf solver.

Comment: How would you start to solve it? Which off-the-shelf solver would you use? Sorry, but I'm not super into this kind of stuff, and even though I learn similar things at school, I'm not learning in english, and sometimes the translation is not trivial.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add a url or reference to the original problem? Even it is not in English, a reference is still very important and useful.